# awk regular expression replace any figure by "", but do not so for numbers between brackets

Tags: awk, regular-expression

- Input shows: `(TJ)-8.5(o12)-3.2(p1)-15.3(ik)-1.2(1)`
- Result has to be: `(TJ)-.(o12)-.(p1)-.(ik)-.(1)`
- Figures of any number of digits contained by brackets should'nt be replaced, but all other figures of any number of digits do.

Comment: can the input contain entries like `123(abc)`, and should the number there be replaced with a dot or nothing?

Comment: As far as I know the only pattern is: ```12.3 or 122.1 or 3.4````and so on. Exactly one digit after the dot, not more, not less and from one up to three digits in front of the dot.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`:

```
gawk '{print gensub(/(\([^)]*\))|[0123456789]+/, "\\1", "g")}'
```

Basically the translation of `sed`'s:

```
sed -E 's/(\([^)]*\))|[0123456789]+/\1/g'
```

Comment: Nice use of a backreference that must be null in the `|` case.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ echo '(TJ)-8.5(o12)-3.2(p1)-15.3(ik)-1.2(1)' |
    awk -v RS='[(][^)]+)' '{gsub(/[0-9]/,""); printf "%s%s", $0, RT}'
(TJ)-.(o12)-.(p1)-.(ik)-.(1)
```